# Why is the classical Secretary Problem about Ranks?

Tags: probability, statistics

The Secretary Problem goes like this:
To an observer there are presented objects in a row.
He may either choose the object one it is presented or move on - there is no turning back. Objective: stop at the best Item.

Some were confused by the notations to come.
I would like to try to explain what this is about.
Consider the literal setting of the problem. You get candidates and know nothing about their quality in advance, yet have to stop at the best candidate with the highest probability possible.
When this problem is put into math usually the papers start with just looking at the rank.

But then you get trouble (you have to model again) if you want to consider the same problem with knowing for an example the candidates are normal distributed and you just do not know the parameters. (The winning chance rises to about 0.58 asymptotically)

The way I propose the problem it is consistent for these cases and I now consider the classical problem as a special case to gain information on dealing with the more abstract problem.

Think of the problem like this:

The items are $F^{-1}(X_1),...,F^{-1}(X_n)$ were the $X_i$are iid. uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$ and $F^{-1}$ is the pseudo inverse of a cumulative distribution function $F$, thus $F^{-1}(X_i) \sim{ F}$.
$F$ may be any continuous distribution function (jumps seem to give the observer an advantage because he does not miss chances so easy, but that is another story).

Let $D: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \{1,...,n\}$ be a stopping time.

The problem then would be to get $\Delta$ such that:

$\max_{D}\inf_{F} P(F^{-1}(X)_{D(F^-1(X))}=\max_{i \leq n} F^{-1}(X_i)) = \max_{D}\inf_{F} P(X_{D(F^{-1}(X))}=\max_{i \leq n} X_i)=\inf_{F} P(X_{\Delta(F^-1(X))}=\max_{i \leq n} X_i)$

Most of the time in literature the problem is solved by finding $\Delta$ with:

$\max_{D}P(X_{D(R(X))}=\max_{i \leq n} X_i)= P(X_{\Delta(R(X))}=\max_{i \leq n} X_i)$. Here $R(X)=R(X_1,...,X_n)=(R_1(X_1),R_2(X_1,X_2),...,R_n(X_1,...,X_n))$ and
$R_i(X_1,...,X_i) = \sum^{i}_{k=1}\mathbf{1}_{X_k \leq X_i}$, the relative rank of the observed item. My question:

Why exactly are the first expressions of my terms the same?

So my question is why does hold:

$\max_{D}\inf_{F} P(F^{-1}(X)_{D(F^-1(X))}=\max_{i \leq n} F^{-1}(X_i))=\max_{D}P(X_{D(R(X))}=\max_{i \leq n} X_i)$

Which is solved provided someone proves:

$\inf_{F} P(X_{D(F^{-1}(X))}=\max_{i \leq n} X_i) \leq P(X_{D(R(X))}=\max_{i \leq n} X_i)$

Note that taking ranks is some sort of protection against any distribution - you do the same thing no matter the distribution.
We just need a distribution so vicious that we rather take ranks.

Thank you very much for your support. Any comment is very welcome.

Comment: In the the classical Secretary Problem, the distribution function is unknown, but you assume that $\Pr(X_i \gt \max(X_1, X_2,\ldots, X_{i-1}) \mid X_1, X_2,\ldots, X_{i-1}  )= \frac1i$ and $\Pr(X_i \gt \max(X_1, X_2,\ldots, X_{i-1}, X_{i+1},\ldots, X_n)   )= \frac1n$

Comment: This is the same as saying yo use the rank!
But why is this the right thing to do?
That's what my question is about!

Comment: The classical secretary problem as I know it has nothing to do with distributions, continuous or otherwise. There are $n$ candidates who appear in a random order, i.e. all $n!$ permutations are equally likely (weaker assumptions may also do, but this is natural enough). Your formulation is almost unrecognizable to me.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR If I understand the question correctly, the essence is the following: suppose you know that the $n$ candidates come from iid. whose distribution is unknown.  The standard problem *models* this by limiting our available information to "just enough to compare ranks", yielding a strategy of $0.37$.  However, if the distribution is known to be normal, there is a better strategy of $0.58$ (by taking into account the quantitative ratings, not just rank). Is there a sequence of distributions which *proves* we can't do better than $0.37$ without some knowledge of the distribution?

Comment: If you know the distribution exactly you allways have 0.58 asymptotically, or better if the distribution has jumps (think of a fair coin - basically can't lose). If you just know the family of distributions sometimes you get 0.58 (normal distribution) sometimes 0.37 and sometimes intermediate results. The way I stated the problem you could only permit certain c.d.f. and would model any case. Now this is the abstraction. What I want is: Why is restricting to rank really the best against an opponent picking F?

Comment: Note that taking ranks you then act the same for any distribution. The task is to find a distribution so vicious you are better of by just taking the ranks for your decisions.

Comment: @ErickWong As I understand it, the classical problem assumes we know nothing at all about the distribution. (The candidates being random samples from an IID distribution is not required; they don't even have to come from a random distribution; they can be arbitrary values just come in a random order.)  
So this question is asking about a _variant_ in which we assume the candidates are actually random samples from a distribution, and framing it as "Why is the classical Secretary Problem about Ranks?".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prove $\sup_D\inf_F P(X_{D(X)} \leq X_{max})=\sup_DP(X_{D(R(X))} \leq X_{max})$ it suffices to prove $\sup_D\inf_F P(X_{D(X)} \leq X_{max}) \leq \sup_DP(X_{D(R(X))} \leq X_{max})$ as you restricted yourself to continious distributions this is clear as here the $R$ serves as some sort of "protection" against $\inf_F$ if you restrict yourself to $\max_{D(R(\dot{}))}$ instead the other inequality is clear - I sense you see this so no furthe discussion.

How to prove the other inequality?

You need a family of distributions so vicious that taking rank's again is the best option. $(\mathscr{U}[\alpha,\beta])_{\alpha < \beta}$ is a family that gets the job done. See here:http://www.jstor.org/stable/2287066?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: I was somewhat blind - I know the result quite well. 
This is all I need, thank you a lot.